# Get all guild ID's with Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I want to get every ID from the servers my bot is on. In the best way please in a list so I could get one ID after another because I need them for my prefix system. I tried a lot of designs but it didn't work right.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`Collection#map`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=map) to map `Client.guilds.cache` ([`GuildManager#cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=cache)) by ID.

---

## Discord JS V12

(not supported anymore)

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("ready", () => {
    const Guilds = client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.id);
    console.log(Guilds);
});

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_ACCESS_TOKEN)
```

## Discord JS V13/14

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: ["GUILDS"],
});

client.on("ready", () => {
    const Guilds = client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.id);
    console.log(Guilds);
});

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_ACCESS_TOKEN);
```

Comment: Isn't this a bad way since the list is just updated when the bot restarts? Idk was just thinking about it

Comment: @Whoozy The cache is being updated automatically when the bot joins/leaves a Guild.

Comment: I recommend running the code above after making sure that the bot was called in a guild (mention, slash command, etc...). This way you're sure that the guild is actually present in the client cache.
As I didn't have this problem before, I think this may be caused by Discord slowly revoking access to developers.